# Spark DataFrame aggregation: windows + partitioning versus groupBy operations

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm looking to perform about five different summarizing techniques over a lot of data. Generally, I'm looking to calculate mean, min, max, stddev, and sum over certain time windows and other dimensions.

Here's about as reproducible an example I can make:

```
import random
import string
import datetime

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as func
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, DoubleType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

########## Setting up DataFrame ##########
def random_date(start, n):
    current = start
    for _ in range(n):
        current = current + datetime.timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(60))
        yield current

start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20, 13, 00)

n_records = 50000000

dates = list(random_date(start_date, n_records))

other_data = []
for d in dates:
    categorical_data = tuple(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(1))
    numerical_data = tuple(random.randrange(100) for _ in range(20))
    other_data.append(categorical_data + numerical_data + (d,))

categorical_columns = ['cat_{}'.format(n) for n in range(1)]
numerical_columns = ['num_{}'.format(n) for n in range(20)]
date_column = ['date']

columns = categorical_columns + numerical_columns + date_column

df = sc.parallelize(other_data).toDF(columns)

df = df.withColumn('date_window', func.window('date', '5 minutes'))

df.registerTempTable('df')

########## End DataFrame setup ##########
```

To date, I've tried two techniques: one using the built-in `DataFrame.groupBy` mechanism; the other using `pyspark.sql.window.Window`'s `orderBy` and `partitionBy` methods.

Generally, the pipeline I've developed looks like this:

1. For each numeric column, group-by the categorical columns `cat_0` and `date_window`, and calculate the five summary statistics listed previously.
2. For the `pyspark.sql.window.Window` approach, join the calculated column directly, using `df.withColumn`. For the `DataFrame.groupBy` approach, track each result DataFrame (each with three columns: two for the grouping columns, and one for the calculated column) - at the end, join each DataFrame by basically performing a reduce operation with the grouping columns as keys.

I've left some of the pipeline code below, but am primarily interested in opinions about 1) whether either of these are "best practices" for this type of work and 2) if not, am I missing something major within the Spark ecosystem that could help me do this much more quickly/with fewer resources?

Currently, the `groupBy` approach has performed a little bit better, but is kind of cumbersome with having to track each grouped-by DataFrame and reduce-join them all at the end. The `Window` approach hasn't been very great, although it's syntactically a little bit cleaner and more maintainable, IMO. In either case, I'm having to allocate a massive amount of compute to get the job to run and write to disk at the end (without repartitioning/coalescing).

```
gb_cols = ['cat_0', 'date_window']
strategies = {'sum', 'mean', 'stddev', 'max', 'min'}

Xcols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('num')]

for col in Xcols[:]:
    for s in strategies:
        new_col = '{}_{}'.format(col, s)
        Xcols.append(new_col)

        if s == 'mean':
            calc_col_series = func.mean(col)
        elif s == 'stddev':
            calc_col_series = func.stddev(col)
        elif s == 'max':
            calc_col_series = func.max(col)
        elif s == 'min':
            calc_col_series = func.min(col)
        elif s == 'sum':
            calc_col_series = func.sum(col)
        elif s == 'median':
            query = '''
                SELECT
                    PERCENTILE_APPROX({}, 0.5)
                FROM df
                GROUP BY {}
            '''.format(col, ','.join(gb_cols))
            calc_col_series = spark.sql(query)

        df = df.withColumn(new_col, calc_col_series.over(agg_window))

        # Differencing inputs
        for difference in range(1, 3 + 1):
            # Last period's datapoints... moved to the future
            led_series = func.lag(df[new_col], difference).over(agg_window.orderBy(window_cols['orderBy']))
            diff_series = df[new_col] - led_series

            new_col_diff = '{}_{}_diff'.format(new_col, difference)
            df = df.withColumn(new_col_diff, diff_series)
            Xcols.append(new_col_diff)
```